# SFINAE and sizeof vs constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, sfinae

Sometimes people write something like the following ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)):

```
template<typename T>
class is_class {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no [2];
    template<typename C> static yes& test(int C::*); // selected if C is a class type
    template<typename C> static no&  test(...);      // selected otherwise
  public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Is there some reason not to replace such constructs (`sizeof`-based) with `constexpr`-based code, such as the following?

```
template<typename T>
class is_class {
    template<typename C> static constexpr bool test(int C::*) { return true; } // selected if C is a class type
    template<typename C> static constexpr bool test(...) { return false; }     // selected otherwise
public:
    static bool constexpr value = test<T>(0);
};
```

I know `constexpr` is a relatively new addition to the language, but is there any reason to prefer the first version other than having to use an old standard (pre-C++11)?

Comment: No. Both are evaluated at compile time. Both examples could use more modern idioms to improve readability. Partial template specialization on a template variable comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options would work. But the difference between them is that the first one doesn't require C++11 while the second one does. And if you are free to use at least C++11 - there is no need to use any of them, there is already [std::is_class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class) in the standard library.

So if you see such code in some project then either this project is supposed to compile without C++11 support or it's some legacy.